# How do I bind my component's scope to mapStateToProps in react-redux?

Tags: react-redux

Its unreasonable to assume my components won't need local state for simple local component flags that don't need to pollute my store, much less need all the code overhead of dispatchers and action handlers. Is local state shunned upon by react-redux? I don't see a work-around for my use case other than of putting everything into my store --way too much work imo.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Yes, local state is shunned by react-redux.

The philosophy of redux is that your components are purely a view of your app state. They themselves should not hold state.

However, before you sigh in exasperation, you should note that one of the great things about redux is that the store is nice to work with. It's just a state tree and any reducer you write only needs to deal with its own portion of that tree. I have some reducers in my apps that are all of five lines:

```
export default const isFullScreen = (state = false, action = null) => {
  if (action && action.type === actions.TOGGLE_FULL_SCREEN) {
    return !state;
  }
  return state;
};
```

The benefits of putting everything, even the small stuff, in your store are many. The biggest one though is that any other component can know the state of any other component through `mapStateToProps`. If you rely on local state, that transparency goes away, and things can (and do) get out of sync.  Another benefit is that you can implement cool time-travel stuff, where you can push and pop snapshots of the state from a state history, and step backwards and forwards through actions in your app (also goes away with local state).

If though, at the end of the day, that is not enough to convince you to put everything in the store, then it is possible to still use local state without breaking redux. I don't recommend it though.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, I wish that was documented a little more clearly in react-redux module and I wish it could disabled the local state of the react components somehow to make that construct very clear.

Comment: It definitely takes some getting used to. I've found it helps to try to make my components pure functional.  As in, don't use ES6 `class` or `React.createComponent`, instead write your component as a function where the props come in as arguments.  That will help you phase out of using local state.

Comment: Well after some more tinkering and converting my app to using this, I went all the way back! I just don't like trying to code reducers and handlers for every little change I make along the way. I want a flexible, light-weight component and I honestly want private state.

I'm reserving my redux store for data that goes to and from my database and some helper variables to go with it, beyond that, the rest is private and this feels way easier to deal with.